# Swift MFMailComposeViewController with XLS attachment, No attachment found

Tags: ios, swift, excel, swift3, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm working on `MFMailComposeViewController` in Swift 3.0 (Xcode 8.2.1) with XLS as an attachment. I've saved an excel file in Cache directory and retrieving the same for an attachment to an email. (see below code)

When I debug the code I see that it prints, "File data loaded.", means that there is data coming from the sandbox(cache). Not sure, this mime type is correct `"application/vnd.ms-excel"`?

To my strange! I don't see a mail body and the attachment. Could you please help?

So far, here is my code:

```
import MessageUI
class ViewController:MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func shareFileViaEmail() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
                mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self


                let paths: [Any] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
                let documentsDirectory: String = paths[0] as! String
                let dataPath: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("record.xls").absoluteURL

                if let fileData = NSData(contentsOf: dataPath) {
                    print("File data loaded.")
                    mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName: "Report")

                }

                mailComposerVC.setSubject("Report")
                mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Message body", isHTML: false)
                self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else{

                print("Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.")
            }
   }
   func mailComposeController(_ controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result:MFMailComposeResult, error:Error?) {

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
   }

}
```

I see the following output in the device: (No attachment & No Email body)

[image: Device Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code works for me.

```
if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {


    let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

    //Set the subject and message of the email
    mailComposer.setSubject("swift")
    mailComposer.setMessageBody("Testing", isHTML: false)
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let filePath = url.appendingPathComponent("nameOfFileHere")?.path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath!) {
        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!) {
            print("File data loaded.")
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName: "nameOfFileHere")
        }
    } else {
        print("FILE NOT AVAILABLE")
    }

    self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes this works for me. what is the file extension that you have?

Comment: Still not working, When I checked my sandbox it has excel file, It also prints "File data loaded", but I don't why it doesn't attach file to an email.

Comment: can you get the body at least in the mail?

Comment: Thanks :) the same code works in another mobile. I don't know why? I was using my mobile before, My mobile has 2 email set up.

Comment: In Settings->mail->Default Account check your account. But for me it works with multiple email set up as well. It uses the default account.